# How does Python 3 know how to pickle extension types, especially Numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pickle, python-c-api

Numpy arrays, being extension types (aka defined using in extensions the C API), declare additional fields outside the scope of the Python interpreter (for example the `data` attribute, which is a `Buffer Structure`, as documented in Numpy's [array interface](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html).
To be able to serialize it, Python 2 used to use the `__reduce__` function as part of the pickle protocol, as stated in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types), and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855156/whats-the-exact-usage-of-reduce-in-pickler).

But, even if `__reduce__` still exists in Python 3, the `Pickle protocol` section (and `Pickling and unpickling extension types` a fortiori) was removed from the doc, so it is unclear what does what.
Moreover, there are additional entries that relate to pickling extension types:

- [copyreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#module-copyreg), described as a `Pickle interface constructor registration for extension types`, but there's no mention of extension types in the copyreg module itself.
- [PEP 3118 -- Revising the buffer protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/) which released a new buffer protocol for Python 3. (and maybe automates pickling for this buffer protocol).
- New-style class: One can assume that the new-style classes have an influence on the pickling process.

So, how does all of this relate to Numpy arrays:

1. Does Numpy array implement special methods, such as `__reduce__` to inform Python on how to pickle them (or `copyreg`)? Numpy objects still expose a `__reduce__` method, but it may be for compatibility reasons.
2. Does Numpy uses Python's C-API structures that are supported out of the box by Pickle (like the new `buffer protocol`), so nothing supplementary is necessary in order to pickle numpy arrays?

Comment: `__reduce__` still exists in Python 3.

Comment: ..[and here is the piece of documentation where `__reduce__` is mentioned in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#object.__reduce__).

Comment: The point is that the mentions to extension types in the `reduce` doc have been removed, even if `reduce` still exists. But that was said is still true, as stated by the accepted answer (and in the following comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 3 `pickle` still [supports `__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__), it is covered under the [*Pickling Class Instances* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances).

Numpy's support has not changed in this regard; it implements `__reduce__` on arrays to support pickling in either Python 2 or 3:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array(0).__reduce__()
(<built-in function _reconstruct>, (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (0,), b'b'), (1, (), dtype('int64'), False, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
```

A three-element tuple is returned, consisting of a function object to recreate the value, a tuple of arguments for that function, and a state tuple to pass no `newinstance.__setstate__()`.

Comment: So what is said in [Pickling and Unpickling extension types](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types) is still true? Why did they move the `__reduce__` doc from `extension types` to the more general `class instances` section?

Comment: @Phylliade: yes, everything is still true. The method is not exclusive for extension types (and the line between custom Python classes and extension types has largely been blurred).

Comment: @Phylliade: `__reduce__` is the lower-level copy protocol implementation; custom Python classes should implement the higher-level (`__getnewargs_ex__ ` / `__getstate__` / `__setstate__`) methods) if possible, a default `__reduce__` implementation then uses those.