# How to serialize Jinja2 template in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, serialization, jinja2

I want to use a Jinja2 template to create a column in a df using PySpark. For example, if I have a column `name`, use the following template to create another column called `new_name`.

```
from jinja2 import Template
TEMPLATE =  """
Hello {{ customize(name) }}!
"""
template = Template(source = TEMPLATE)
template.globals["customize"] = customize
def customize(name):
    return name+"san"
def udf_foo(name):
    template.render(name)
convertUDF = udf(lambda z: udf_foo(z),StringType())
df = df.select(df.name)
df1 = df.withColumn("new_name", convertUDF(col("name")))
```

Executing the code, I get the following error which I think is because the template cannot be serialized successfully.

```
An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 189, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 541, in loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
TypeError: Template.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source''. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 189, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 541, in loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
TypeError: Template.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'
```

I have tried using other serializers like Pickle, Kryo etc but the error persists.

1. Does anyone think it might not be serialization related error?
2. Do you know how to fix this so that we can use Jinja2 with Pyspark?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `Template` object is unfortunately unpickalable..having said that there is a workaround: Create a instance of template object inside the definition of udf then render and return the string value

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.udf
def render(name):
    template = Template(source=TEMPLATE)
    template.globals["customize"] = customize

    return template.render(name=name)


df1 = df.withColumn("new_name", render("name"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @shubham-sharma. Could you explain two things you mentioned in the answer - why is Template unpickleable and how does the solution prevent serialization of Template.

Comment: How does the solution prevent the serialization of templates? Any objects that are defined outside the scope of your UDF functions are serialized by spark  when transmitting the code over the network. So, if you create the instance inside the function scope serialization is not necessary

Comment: Regarding the first question thats the way the Template class is implemented. Looking at the source code it seems the Template class does not define the __reduce__ method which is required to reconstruct the object in case the object contains non-serializable attributes. You can read more about the __reduce__ method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855156/whats-the-exact-usage-of-reduce-in-pickler

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Shubham Sharma does solve the problem since the template is unpicklable. However, UDFs are executed row-wise, meaning that the complexity to render the template changes from O(1) to O(n) in the solution he provided, where n is the number of rows in the dataset. Therefore, this approach can be very time-consuming when working with large datasets.

So, to reduce this overhead, I improved Shubham Sharma's solution by using Bytecode Caching, now supported by Jinja2. I simply pass an instance of the `FileSystemBytecodeCache`, which ships with Jinja2, into the Jinja2 environment before rendering. **This approach reduced the execution time of some PySpark jobs I work with by 15 times**. Here's a reference [link](https://mayuresh82.github.io/2021/08/23/j2_templating/) for this feature and its performance.

Here's a brief excerpt of the code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from jinja2 import (
    FileSystemLoader,
    FileSystemBytecodeCache,
    Environment
)

TEMPLATE =  """
Hello {{ customize(name) }}!
"""
_tpl_path = "/tmp/template.j2"

fs_loader = FileSystemLoader(searchpath="/")
fs_bytecode_cache = FileSystemBytecodeCache("/tmp/")
e = Environment(loader=fs_loader, bytecode_cache=fs_bytecode_cache)

@F.udf
def render(name):
  if not Path(_tpl_path).exists():
      with open(_tpl_path, "w") as tpl_file:
          template_file.write(TEMPLATE)
  
  tpl_object = e.get_template(_tpl_path)
  return tpl_object.render(name)

df1 = df.withColumn("new_name", render("name"))
```

In this scenario, Jinja2 automatically stores a compiled bytecode for the template at the Spark work node file system, under the folder `/tmp/`. This occurs upon the first invocation of the render UDF function, which is performed by the *%timeit* function. Thus, if a template is only rendered once, this cache has no effect. The true advantage of the file system-based cache is observed during subsequent invocations or with very large datasets.