# Achieving Microsecond-level Data Retrieval with Custom Data Types in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**Problem Description:**

I'm currently working on a Python project that involves multiprocessing and requires efficient data communication. The data I'm dealing with is stored in a list, and each element of the list is a custom data type. The challenge is to achieve ultra-fast data retrieval, aiming for microsecond-level performance.

**Specific Requirements:**

1. **Data Content:** The data to be communicated is a list containing custom data types like QPointF in pyqt. For example [QPointF(i, 100) for i in range(0, 10000)].
2. **Performance Goal:** The data retrieval process needs to be as fast as possible, with a target of microsecond-level efficiency.
3. **Usability:** Once the data is retrieved, it should be directly usable without additional processing or organization.

**Previous Attempts:**

I've explored various solutions within the **`multiprocessing`** module, including:

- **`multiprocessing.Queue`**
- **`multiprocessing.Pipe`**
- **`multiprocessing.managers.ShareableList`**
- **`multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`**

Unfortunately, none of these approaches have met the desired speed and usability criteria. Both **`Queue`** and **`Pipe`** exhibit retrieval times in the millisecond range, while **`ShareableList`** and **`SharedMemory`** lack support for lists containing custom data types, requiring additional post-retrieval organization.

**Request for Guidance:**

I'm seeking recommendations or insights into alternative methods or best practices within the Python **`multiprocessing`** module or any other relevant library to achieve efficient microsecond-level data communication for a list containing custom data types.

**Summary of Question:**

What other methods or approaches can be suggested to achieve high-speed data communication (microsecond-level) within the **`multiprocessing`** module when working with lists containing custom data types? Previous attempts with **`Queue`**, **`Pipe`**, **`ShareableList`**, and **`SharedMemory`** have fallen short. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR - It's neigh impossible in out-of-the-box Python to get microsecond timings. Below is a possible home-rolled solution in pure Python using SharedMemory that gets close and may inspire your own development**

Microsecond timing in Python is a pretty brutal objective. (Insert obligatory ranting about using Python in performance sensitive tasks) I think focusing on low latency and allowing for some missed messages can get us close to what you want.

The method I have here is a double [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). The first buffer is fixed stride for rapid lookups and tells you where to find the start/stop points in the other buffer. It's hard to accomplish what you want with a single buffer since you don't mention fixed datasizes, and the double circular buffer helps with that, where the first is fixed stride (so we can jump straight to the data of interest), and the second is whatever size to accommodate the data (but we can jump straight to the data of interest since the first one already told us where it is). Essentially one is just a memory map of pickled objects in the other. In this implementation, data can be overwritten before being read, and it supports arbitrarily high numbers of consumers. It could be adjusted to wait until after read to overwrite in a single consumer, no lost messages configuration. I'm sure alot of optimizations are available here, given better knowledge about the data being moved.

I put a ton of comments to explain the logic, but feel free to post follow up questions in comments.

I made an assumption that all your objects are picklable or can be made to be so, since you mention `multiprocessing.Queue` for example which already has that requirement.

Your requests:

- Data Content

  - The object you mention has a `__reduce__` method [according to the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QPointF.html) so it should work just fine, as will most common objects. If it doesn't, you can always wrap it, though I know you had a no "[additional] organization" requirement.
- Performance Goal

  - It's in the 5 - 20 microseconds range for most reasonably sized datatypes, and may do better on very small objects, a single int is about 1.2 microseconds in my test.
- Usability

  - This provides objects back that will be as similar as the solutions you tested, and in my tests I didn't find any differences between what went in and what came out, though it does have a class wrapped around it, so there is some overhead associated with, which is unavoidable anyways.

Performance:
On my Windows 10, i9-10900K, 2667 MHz RAM, Python 3.11.4 I could get a 1000 `int` `numpy.array` read time down to about 4.8 microseconds each, and a single `int` read around 1.2 microseconds each.

```
import sys
import pickle
import multiprocessing.shared_memory as sm
import time
import uuid
import struct

# PyPi libraries
import numpy as np

# String encoding for storing in the buffer
ENCODING = 'UTF-8'

def getuuid():
    return bytes(str(uuid.uuid4()), encoding=ENCODING)

# GuyQianMessage
class GQM:
    '''
    A low read-latency message service between processes using multiprocessing
    Uses a circular buffer - older data is eventually lost, any process
        reading from this buffer which falls behind will miss entries
    DIR buffer contains UUID, index and start stop positions in the data buffer
    DAT buffer is the data buffer and contains UUID and pickle bytes
    
    Use `put` to put data into the buffer
    Use `get` to retrieve data from the buffer
    Use `get` with verbose=True to get back index and UUID for identifying 
        skipped or repeated data
    
    Typical use case:
    Proc 1:
        gqm = GQM(True)
        while True:
            # Generate data
            gqm.put(mydatatosend)
        # Exit time
        gqm.close()
    
    Proc 2:
        gqm = GQM()
        while True:
            data, index, uuid = gqm.get(verbose=True)
            if uuid == lastuuid:
                # repeat data
                pass
            if index > lastindex + 1:
                # missed data
                pass
            # process data
    
    '''
    
    # These are unique names for the memory space
    SHARED_MEMORY_NAME_DIR = 'SPECIAL_NAME_FOR_GUYQIAN_77500126_DIR'
    SHARED_MEMORY_NAME_DAT = 'SPECIAL_NAME_FOR_GUYQIAN_77500126_DAT'
    
    # Capture the length of a UUID (its stored in the buffer with the entry)
    UUID_LEN = len(getuuid())
    
    # How many positions to keep in the directory
    #   By checking indexes, processes can determine if they need to also 
    #   check an earlier position for data
    #   Eaching backwards improperly is caught by UUID matching
    DIR_POS_COUNT = 1024
    # The data type of the position in the DIR buffer
    DIR_POS_TYPE = 'L'
    # Pre calculate how much space the position takes up
    DIR_POS_LEN = struct.calcsize(f'<{DIR_POS_TYPE}')
    # Pre generate the format string for each entry in the DIR buffer
    DIR_ROW_FMT = f'<{UUID_LEN}sLLL'
    # Pre calculate the stride in the DIR buffer
    DIR_STRIDE = struct.calcsize(DIR_ROW_FMT)
    # Pre calculate the total DIR buffer size
    BUFFER_SIZE_DIR = struct.calcsize(
        f'<{DIR_POS_TYPE}{DIR_STRIDE * DIR_POS_COUNT}c'
    )
    
    # Set the size of the DAT buffer
    #   Larger holds more entries before overwriting
    #   May need to be high for large datatypes
    BUFFER_SIZE_DAT = int(1e6)
    
    def __init__(self, provider=False):
        '''
        Initialize with provider set to True for the data creator
        Initialize with no arguments or provider set to False for data users
        
        Returns a GQM object
        '''
        # Keep this flag - prevent consumers from trying to put data in
        self.provider = provider
        # If this is the provider, create the buffers using the precalculated
        #   sizes and names
        if self.provider:
            self.smo_dir = sm.SharedMemory(
                name=GQM.SHARED_MEMORY_NAME_DIR,
                create=True,
                size=GQM.BUFFER_SIZE_DIR
            )
            self.smo_dat = sm.SharedMemory(
                name=GQM.SHARED_MEMORY_NAME_DAT,
                create=True,
                size=GQM.BUFFER_SIZE_DAT
            )
        # If this is the consumer, hook into the existing buffer
        else:
            self.smo_dir = sm.SharedMemory(name=GQM.SHARED_MEMORY_NAME_DIR)
            self.smo_dat = sm.SharedMemory(name=GQM.SHARED_MEMORY_NAME_DAT)
        # This is the current byte position in the DAT buffer to write the 
        #   next item to
        self.dat_pos = 0
        # This is the current row numbre in the DIR buffer to write the 
        #   next look up info to
        self.dir_pos = 0
        # This is the index of the item being put in so that consumers can
        #   determine if they have missed any data
        self.index = 0
    
    def close(self):
        '''
        Call this function from the provider to close out the buffers
        DO NOT call this function before all consumers are finished
        
        Consumers do not need to do anything when finished
        '''
        # Clean up the buffers by unlinking
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html
        if not self.provider:
            # Only the provider should call the close function
            raise AssertionError('This is not a provider! '\
                '- Unlink only from provider!')
        self.smo_dir.unlink()
        self.smo_dat.unlink()
    
    def put(self, obj):
        '''
        Add data to the buffer
        
        Returns
            index of the item added
            a UUID for the item added
        '''
        # Only providers should call put
        if not self.provider:
            raise AssertionError('Put called from consumer!')
        
        # Pickle the object
        #   If it fails, it may not be picklable, see error message below
        try:
            objp = pickle.dumps(obj)
        except TypeError:
            # Capture this error to help developers understand how to fix it
            raise TypeError('Most likely this error was thrown because an '\
                'object which cannot be pickled was passed as a message. '\
                '\n\tFor custom classes, add a __reduce__ method.' \
                '\n\tSee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855156'
            )
        except:
            # If something else happened raise the error as is
            raise
        
        # Calculate the amount of space necessary in the DAT buffer
        space_req = GQM.UUID_LEN + len(objp)
        # Check if there is that much left
        #   If not, reset to the beginning of the buffer
        #   Relies on the UUID's to stop improper reads
        #   This makes it a circular buffer
        if self.dat_pos + space_req > GQM.BUFFER_SIZE_DAT:
            self.dat_pos = 0
        # The bytes of the block to write the data to
        start = self.dat_pos
        stop = self.dat_pos + space_req
        # Generate a new UUID to use for this entry so that it can be 
        #   uniquely identified
        uuid = getuuid()
        
        # Put the data into the DAT buffer first
        self.smo_dat.buf[start:stop] = struct.pack(
            f'<{space_req}s',
            uuid + objp
        )
        
        # Next put the data into the DIR buffer
        self._put_dir_row(self.dir_pos, uuid, self.index, start, stop)
        # Lastly update the current entry marker for the DIR buffer
        self._put_dir_pos(self.dir_pos)
        
        # Increment the index to track how many items have been put into the
        #   buffer
        self.index += 1
        # Increment the dir_pos for the next call and wrap on the total length
        #   to fulfill circular buffer property
        self.dir_pos += 1
        self.dir_pos %= GQM.DIR_POS_COUNT
        # Record the next position to start writing to the DAT buffer
        self.dat_pos = stop
        # Return the index and UUID in case they are to be used for something
        return self.index, uuid
    
    def get(self, verbose=False, pos_override=None):
        '''
        Retrieves the latest data from the buffer
        To check if data was skipped or is repeated, check index and uuid
        
        Returns
            The data object
            index of this entry (if verbose)
            uuid of this entry (if verbose)
        
        '''
        # Allow a pos override for testing or advanced usage
        if pos_override is None:
            pos = self._get_dir_pos()
        else:
            # Could add some logic for negatives to allow retrieving previous
            #   entries blindly without checking positions and indexes, etc
            pos = pos_override
        
        # Retrieve the information from the DIR buffer
        uuid_dir, index, start, end = self._get_dir_row(pos)
        # Retrieve the data from the DAT buffer
        uuid_dat, pickledata = struct.unpack(
            f'<{GQM.UUID_LEN}s{end - start - GQM.UUID_LEN}s',
            self.smo_dat.buf[start: end]
        )
        # Verify that the UUID's match
        #   If they don't match the DAT could have been updated while we were
        #   reading the DIR buffer 
        #   It should be possible to resolve by simply recalling get
        # If this triggers often, the DAT buffer may be too small
        if not uuid_dat == uuid_dir:
            raise AssertionError('Failed to retrieve matching UUID from data')
        # Read the object back
        outobject = pickle.loads(pickledata)
        # Return the object (and index and UUID if requested)
        if verbose:
            return outobject, index, uuid_dat
        return outobject
    
    def _get_indices_dir(self, pos):
        # Get the indices of the DIR buffer entry
        #   The position indicator is first, and then pos strides is the start
        #   of that entry in the buffer
        start = GQM.DIR_POS_LEN + GQM.DIR_STRIDE * pos
        # Because the DIR buffer is fixed strides, we can just add the stride
        #   to the start to get the end
        return start, start + GQM.DIR_STRIDE
    
    def _put_dir_row(self, pos, uuid, index, start, stop):
        # Put data into a row in the DIR buffer (reverse of _get_dir_row)
        # Get the start and stop positions
        startdir, stopdir = self._get_indices_dir(pos)
        # Put the data in using the pre-generated fmt string
        self.smo_dir.buf[startdir: stopdir] = struct.pack(
            GQM.DIR_ROW_FMT,
            uuid,
            index,
            start,
            stop
        )
    
    def _get_dir_row(self, pos=None):
        # Get a row from the DIR buffer (reverse of _put_dir_row)
        # Allow position overrides for testing or advanced usage
        if pos is None:
            pos = self._get_dir_pos()
        # Get the start and stop positions in the DIR buffer
        start, stop = self._get_indices_dir(pos)
        # Retrieve and unpack the data using the pre-generated fmt string
        uuid, index, startdat, stopdat = struct.unpack(
            GQM.DIR_ROW_FMT,
            self.smo_dir.buf[start: stop]
        )
        # Return all the data collectd
        return uuid, index, startdat, stopdat
    
    def _put_dir_pos(self, pos):
        # Update the current DIR buffer position (reverse of _get_dir_pos)
        self.smo_dir.buf[0: GQM.DIR_POS_LEN] = struct.pack(
            f'<{GQM.DIR_POS_TYPE}',
            pos
        )
    
    def _get_dir_pos(self):
        # Retrieve teh current DIR buffer position (reverse of _put_dir_pos)
        next_pos = struct.unpack(
            f'<{GQM.DIR_POS_TYPE}',
            self.smo_dir.buf[0: GQM.DIR_POS_LEN]
        )
        # Struct unpack returns a tuple even for a single item in the fmt str
        return next_pos[0]


def gt(s=0):
    # A convenience function for returning times for rough performance calc
    return time.perf_counter() * 1e6 - s

def _demo():
    gqmp = GQM(True)
    gqmp2 = GQM()
    
    # A variety of data types to demonstrate that it can recover the object
    test_data = [
        1,
        'abc',
        b'/x00/x01',
        {'abc': 10},
        list(range(10)),
        np.array(range(100, 1100), int),
        [{'a': [{'b': {'c': [1, 'a',]}}]}]
    ]
    
    for test_point in test_data:
        gqmp.put(test_point)
        x = gqmp2.get()
        assert(pickle.dumps(x) == pickle.dumps(test_point))
    
    print('Example get: ', gqmp2.get(verbose=True))
    
    gqmp.put(np.array(range(1000), int))
    n = int(1e5)
    s = gt()
    for i in range(n):
        gqmp2.get()
    unit_time = gt(s) / n
    print(f'get time: {unit_time:.2f} u-sec')
    # Approx 4.8 u-sec per read
    
    gqmp.close()

def _test():
    
    # Check if u-sec write/read is even feasible
    n = int(1e5)
    mydata = np.array(range(100), int)
    s = gt()
    for i in range(n):
        mypick = pickle.dumps(mydata)
        mynewdata = pickle.loads(mypick)
    unit_time = gt(s) / n # ~8.1
    print(f'Pickle/Unpickle time: {unit_time:.2f} u-sec')
    # Not really , approx 8.1 u-sec per write-read
    
    # Check if u-sec read only is feasible
    n = int(1e5)
    mydata = np.array(range(100), int)
    mypick = pickle.dumps(mydata)
    s = gt()
    for i in range(n):
        mynewdata = pickle.loads(mypick)
    unit_time = gt(s) / n # ~2.5
    print(f'Unpickle time:        {unit_time:.2f} u-sec')
    # Maybe , approx 2.5 u-sec per read

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
        _test()
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'demo':
        _demo()
```

Here is a small diagram that briefly shows how the memory is organized.
[How the memory is organized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odmMF.png)

Comment: Thank you for the methods you provided, but after testing, it still cannot meet my requirements. When my list is [QPointF(i, 100) for i in range(0, 1000)], the testing time takes more than 2 milliseconds. When the list is [QPointF(i, 100) for i in range(0, 10000)], the testing time takes more than 20 milliseconds. It takes too much time during pickling.

Comment: Is there some way you can pass the values for the QPointF instead of requiring the whole object on both sides? If you really need it, you must either live with rebuilding the object or you are probably in the territory of writing your own C-extensions, though I am not familiar enough with it myself to provide any code.